# How can I parse a String(not a json object) which is in jsonArray format in rails?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my value String form of JSON array(Not a JSON Object)

```
value= "[{\"a\":\"test a\"},{\"b\":\"test b updated\"}]"
```

when I tried to convert it to JSON using

```
value=value.to_json
#value= "\"[{\\\"a\\\":\\\"test a\\\"},{\\\"b\\\":\\\"test b updated\\\"}]\""
```

but I want my value like this

```
{"a":"test a","b":"test b updated"}
```

Any Suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to turn the JSON string into a Ruby value:

```
arr = JSON.parse(value)
# => [ { "a" => "test a" },
#      { "b" => "test b updated" } ]
```

This will return a Ruby array whose items are hashes.

Next you need to merge the hashes into a single hash:

```
combined_hash = arr.reduce({}, &:merge)
# => { "a" => "test a",
#      "b" => "test b updated" }
```

Finally, turn the hash back into JSON:

```
puts combined_hash.to_json
# => {"a":"test a","b":"test b updated"}
```

All together:

```
arr = JSON.parse(value)
combined_hash = arr.reduce({}, &:merge)
puts combined_hash.to_json
# => {"a":"test a","b":"test b updated"}
```

You can see it in action here: http://ideone.com/l5BAiw

Comment: Thanks a lot Jordan.You saved My day .Now i am like up-vote your answer 100 times if i am able to : ) : ) .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like below:

```
json = JSON.parse(value).to_s
```

to_s is additionally added to convert it to string.

Comment: In which step i need to use this.FYI In first step the value is String in form of json Array(really not a json array).And the end answer i need is Json not string.